# How can update a materialized view at a certain time in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

For examle, I want to update the following materialized view everyday at 23:30.
What should I write after the START WITH and NEXT clause ?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_example REFRESH COMPLETE  
       START WITH 
       NEXT
AS
```

Comment: *START WITH Clause*: Specify a datetime expression for the first automatic refresh time. *NEXT Clause*: Specify a datetime expression for calculating the interval between automatic refreshes. Please clarify your current concern about these values.

Answer (score 0):

Start *right now*, and do it every day at 23:30 as

```
create materialized view test_example
refresh complete
start with sysdate 
next trunc(sysdate) + 23/24 + 30/(24*60)
as select ...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible; try it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified answer of @Littlefoot:

edit: addition: if you want it to start today at 23:30 you would go like

```
create materialized view test_example
refresh complete
start with trunc(sysdate) + 23.5/24
next trunc(sysdate) + 23.5/24 + 1
as select ...
```